# how to efficiently locate a value from one table among values from another table, with SQL

Tags: postgresql, join

I have a problem in Postgresql which I find even difficult to describe in the title: I have two tables, containing each a range of values very similar but not identical.  Suppose I have values like 0, 10, 20, 30, ... in one, and 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 19, 25, 26, ... in the second one (these are milliseconds).  For each value of the second one I want to find the values immediately lower and higher in the first one.  So, for the value 12 it would give me 10 and 20.  I'm doing it like this :

```
SELECT s.*, MAX(v1."millisec") AS low_v,  MIN(v2."millisec") AS high_v
FROM "signals" AS s, "tracks" AS v1, "tracks" AS v2 
WHERE   v1."millisec" <= s."d_time"  
    AND v2."millisec" > s."d_time" 
GROUP BY s."d_time", s."field2";     -- this is just an example
```

And it works ... but it is very slow once I process several thousands of lines, even with indexes on s."d_time" and v.millisec.  So, I think there must be a much better way to do it, but I fail to find one.  Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Does the answer need to be in pure SQL? Are you already using some procedural language with regard to this query?

Comment: It can be pl/pgsql, or even python, but yes it would be better within Postgresql because it's part of a function which is itself part of an automatic processing.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select s.*, 
      (select millisec 
         from tracks t 
        where t.millisec <= s.d_time 
        order by t.millisec desc 
        limit 1
      ) as low_v,

      (select millisec 
         from tracks t 
        where t.millisec > s.d_time 
        order by t.millisec asc  
        limit 1
      ) as high_v
 from signals s;
```

- Be sure you have an index for track.millisec;
- If you had just created
  the index, you'll need to analyze the table to take advantage of it.

Comment: Thanks Christian B. Almeida,  your solution works very well.  See my comments to joop above, I'll select the best solution asap.

Answer (score 0):

Naive (trivial) way to find the preceding and next value.

```
   -- the data (this could have been part of the original question)
CREATE TABLE table_one (id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , msec INTEGER NOT NULL -- index maight help
        );

CREATE TABLE table_two (id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , msec INTEGER NOT NULL -- index maight help
        );

INSERT INTO table_one(msec) VALUES (0), ( 10), ( 20), ( 30);
INSERT INTO table_two(msec) VALUES (1), ( 5), ( 6), ( 9), ( 10), ( 12), ( 19), ( 25), ( 26);

  -- The query: find lower/higher values in table one
  -- , but but with no values between "us" and "them".
  --
SELECT this.msec AS this
        , prev.msec AS prev
        , next.msec AS next
FROM table_two this
LEFT JOIN table_one prev ON prev.msec < this.msec AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_one nx WHERE nx.msec < this.msec AND nx.msec > prev.msec)
LEFT JOIN table_one next ON next.msec > this.msec AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_one nx WHERE nx.msec > this.msec AND nx.msec < next.msec)
        ;
```

---

### Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
INSERT 0 9
 this | prev | next 
------+------+------
    1 |    0 |   10
    5 |    0 |   10
    6 |    0 |   10
    9 |    0 |   10
   10 |    0 |   20
   12 |   10 |   20
   19 |   10 |   20
   25 |   20 |   30
   26 |   20 |   30
(9 rows)
```

Comment: joop, I hadn't seen your proposition and implemented already the solution proposed by Christian B. Almeida, which works fine.  I'll check yours and see if it's better, then give a feedback.

Comment: joop, I tried your proposition but I couldn't get it to work as well as the one proposed by Christian B. Almeida.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select * from signals s,
 (select millisec low_value,
     lead(millisec) over (order by millisec) high_value from tracks) intervals 
where s.d_time between low_value and high_value-1
```

For this type of problem "Window functions" are ideal see : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Thank you Rémy.  I like this nice solution, but it is 50% slower than the one from Christian above, and it forgets the signals before the first low value as well as those after the last high value.

Comment: Effectively my solution is slower. This does not seem to come from the window function, but from the joint. I'm very surprised than a "select *,(select ..) low_value" is more efficient than a joint but it's a fact.